# Which transport will be used by SignalR between android app and IIS server that supported Websocket?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, signalr

I want to write an android application and I want to know if SignalR use websocket or something else for communicating between server and client, before I do that.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, SignalR will try to work with web sockets, if they are not available in the underlying platform, it will fall back to SSE, and then to long polling.

Xamarin/Mono current implementation has [some issues with web sockets](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24164/signalr-websockets), even though SignalR supports it, so web sockets will not be available.

If your app is made with Xamarin (as you tagged your question), the best protocol you will get is SSE (server sent events). But in my experience (I´ve got an app working with it) this protocol is fast and stable enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

From the signalR webpage

> SignalR uses the new WebSocket transport where available, and falls
>   back to older transports where necessary.

From the Xamarin forums and youtube, It seems people have successfully implemented websocket transport with [SignalR on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWLieVqeB1U)

**What else can I use?**

Socket.IO for an HTML5 application(With NodeIIS),GCM or Firebase like push notifications for native on any webserver

Comment: but it is possible with xamarin.

Comment: Of-cource ,I've never thought of Xamarin,You might want to add Xamarin tag to your question